# How to build a Selenium Web Driver java application using Ant (outside Eclipse ...)?

Tags: java, selenium, ant, build

first of all ..... I'm a newbie of Apache Ant.

I'm trying to use it for building a simple java application using Selenium Web Driver libraries.

I started from the Tutorial: Hello World with Apache Ant (ref. http://ant.apache.org/manual/index.html) to build a simple "Hello world" that explain also how to use external libraries (in the example the log4J library ...).

All works fine .. Then I've tried to change my first build file to apdapt it at my java application using Selenium Web Driver libraries.

Here you're my directory organization ....

[image]

My java sources are in another directory in my disk, but it's not this the problem (I think ...)

Under the lib directory I've the selenium-java-2.46.0.jar and under the libs subdirectory I've all the others selenium libraries so ...

[image]

(note, that it's NOT a complete list of all the libraries ... It's only to explain my file organization ...).

Here you are my build.xml file ...

```
<project name="Bdo" basedir="." default="main">

<property name="src.dir"     value="D:/Cesare/Lavoro/WorkspaceEclipse/TestSelenium/TestSeleniumProgetti/src/myProjects"/>
<property name="build.dir"   value="Bdo"/>
<property name="classes.dir" value="${build.dir}/classes"/>
<property name="jar.dir"     value="${build.dir}/jar"/>
<property name="main-class"  value="myProjects.bdoTest_01"/>
<property name="lib.dir" value="lib"/>

<path id="classpath">
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar"/>
</path>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}" classpathref="classpath"/>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${classes.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="../../${lib.dir}/selenium-java-2.46.0.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/apache-mime4j-0.6.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/bsh-1.3.0.jar ../../${lib.dir}/cglib-nodep-2.1_3.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/commons-codec-1.10.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar ../../${lib.dir}/commons-exec-1.3.jar ../../${lib.dir}/commons-io-2.4.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/commons-lang3-3.4.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar ../../${lib.dir}/cssparser-0.9.16.jar ../../${lib.dir}/gson-2.3.1.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/guava-18.0.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar ../../${lib.dir}/hamcrest-library-1.3.jar ../../${lib.dir}/htmlunit-2.17.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/htmlunit-core-js-2.17.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/httpclient-4.4.1.jar ../../${lib.dir}/httpcore-4.4.1.jar ../../${lib.dir}/httpmime-4.4.1.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/jcommander-1.29.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/jetty-io-9.2.11.v20150529.jar ../../${lib.dir}/jetty-util-9.2.11.v20150529.jar ../../${lib.dir}/jna-4.1.0.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/jna-platform-4.1.0.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/junit-dep-4.11.jar ../../${lib.dir}/nekohtml-1.9.22.jar ../../${lib.dir}/netty-3.5.7.Final.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/phantomjsdriver-1.2.1.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/sac-1.3.jar ../../${lib.dir}/serializer-2.7.2.jar ../../${lib.dir}/testng-6.8.5.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/websocket-api-9.2.11.v20150529.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/websocket-client-9.2.11.v20150529.jar ../../${lib.dir}/websocket-common-9.2.11.v20150529.jar ../../${lib.dir}/xalan-2.7.2.jar ../../${lib.dir}/libs/xercesImpl-2.11.0.jar  ../../${lib.dir}/libs/xml-apis-1.4.01.jar "/>            
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<target name="run" depends="jar">
    <java fork="true" classname="${main-class}">
        <classpath>
            <path refid="classpath"/>
            <path location="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
        </classpath>
    </java>
</target>

<target name="clean-build" depends="clean,jar"/>

<target name="main" depends="clean,run"/>
```

When I execute the command

```
ant run
```

all works fine and I can see my application working ...

When I try to execute the jar using the command

```
java -jar Bdo.jar
```

I've the following error

[image]

I think that something is going wrong about the ClassPath, but seems that all the library paths are ok ....

Any suggestion?

Thank you very much in advance !!!

Cesare

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the paths in your classpath do not contain the libs directory.  gson-2.3.1.jar is one such path.

Comment: @Cesare we all make them, I've made this one a lot so I recognize it quickly.  Would you be so kind as to accept my answer since it answered your question?  Thanks!